# How to validate email address is valid PayPal email address or not in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I Need to validate the correct PayPal email address. because I need to send transfer money to that PayPal email address.

this code is working before. but now it is not validated.

my code is

```
 $ch = curl_init();
    //parameters of requests
    $nvpStr = 'emailAddress=' . $request->email . '&matchCriteria=NONE';

    // RequestEnvelope fields
    $detailLevel    = urlencode("ReturnAll");
    $errorLanguage  = urlencode("en_US");
    $nvpreq = "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=$errorLanguage&requestEnvelope.detailLevel=$detailLevel&";
    $nvpreq .= "&$nvpStr";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    $headerArray = array(
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID:" . env('PAYPAL_USERNAME'),
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD:" . env('PAYPAL_PASSWORD'),
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE:" . env('PAYPAL_SIGNATURE'),
        "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT:JSON",
        "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT:JSON",
        "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID:" . env('PAYPAL_APP_ID') //,
        //"X-PAYPAL-SANDBOX-EMAIL-ADDRESS:$sandboxEmail" //comment this line in production mode. IT IS JUST FOR SANDBOX TEST
    );

    $url = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerArray);
    $paypalResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    //echo $paypalResponse;   //if you want to see whole PayPal response then uncomment it.
    curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($paypalResponse);

    if ($data->responseEnvelope->ack == 'Success')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

I'm getting this in response
[image]

I'm working on PHP laravel.

Please help if anyone is having any idea.

Comment: If you're using a third party service that suddenly stops working (without you changing anything), then you should start with contacting the service provider (paypal) and check if there are any changes/issues with your account/their api. We can't check/debug that since we're not them.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm not using any third services.  https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus

Comment: You're literally asking about Paypal's API, which is the third party in this context.

Comment: now it is working. It is from the Paypal end.

Answer (score 0):

The error ID and correlation ID are blotted out in the question's screenshot. Way to make it impossible for anyone to give a precise answer as to what the problem is.

A likely issue is that `&matchCriteria=NONE` is not supported for GetVerifiedStatus. Instead, pass something like `&matchCriteria=NAME` as well as `&FirstName=xxxxx` and `&LastName=xxxxx`.

If you don't want to prompt users for match criteria, another different solution would be to use a [Connect with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/integrate/) button for them to log in.